# How to force an authoritative and non-authoritative synchronization for DFSR-replicated SYSVOL

Tags: active-directory, sysvol

I Got the answer that:- 
In the ADSIEDIT.MSC tool modify the following distinguished name (DN) value and attribute on each of the domain controllers that you want to make non-authoritative:

CN=SYSVOL Subscription,CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-LocalSettings,CN=,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=

msDFSR-Enabled=FALSE

Here is my ADSIEDIT Window, but i am not able to find, CN=SYSVOL Subscription,CN=Domain System Volume,CN=DFSR-LocalSettings,CN=,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=

Please find below print-screen
[image: ADSI EDIT]

I know it seems like very silly question, but where can i find? Please let me know, if you want me to delete this question. I will delete it, just need your help, to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Expand `Default naming context > DC=(domain),DC=(local) > OU=Domain Controllers > CN=(DC name) > CN=Domain System Volume`

[image: ADSiEdit]